# Trailing Slash Issue with WP in a Vagrant Dev Environment

Tags: wordpress, nginx, vagrant

I have a Wordpress site running in a Vagrant development environment. When I load up `http://localhost:8080`, the site comes up fine, but as soon as I try to access the admin by going to `http://localhost:8080/wp-admin`, I'm redirected to `http://localhost/wp-admin/`.

Two things here:

1. Something (Wordpress?) is forcing the trailing slash (which would be fine, except...).
2. In the trailing slash redirection, the port is getting lost (which is very much not fine).

I've tried adding the `port_in_redirect` directive (using both values, to be honest) that I've seen in other answers to similar questions, but it changed nothing. This seems to be a Wordpress, ahem, feature, but I can't find anything to explain its purpose or that helps me keep it from breaking things. I'm hoping someone can help.

My Nginx `server` block:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name localhost;
  root        /vagrant/www;
  index       index.php;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/project.vm.access.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/project.vm.error.log;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests so the admin interface
  # works correctly. I've tried with and without this. No difference.
  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  # Cache static files
  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }
  location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    allow all;
  }

  location ~ /\. {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
  }

  location ~ ~$ {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

In my `wp-config.php` file, I have the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants set.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:8080');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:8080');
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: If it is Nginx doing it, try including the `server_port` in the wp-admin rewrite: `rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host:$server_port$uri/ permanent;`

Comment: I tried that the other day. No joy. Thanks.

Comment: helped me @myanimal. It's in the offical WP nginx docs https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

Answer (score 0):

I recently face the same problem after moving a WordPress installation from a server to a local Vagrant instance and solved it adding:

```
define('RELOCATE',true);
```

to wp-config.php file and going to `http://localhost:8080/wp-login.php`

I found the solution at http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method, I think there you can find a few other ways to deal with the issue of moving a WP installation from one server to another.